# VSC13 - cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays / for STRINGS

Tags: arrays, string, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, initialization

I understand that Microsoft Visual Studios Community 2013 has a problem with the initialization of arrays, but how do I work around this specifically for strings?  And please try to explain the answer well, I am still quite new to this.

```
class a{
public:
    string words[3] = {"cake","pie","steak"};
};
```

Comment: From you question it is hard to understand what language do you use?

Comment: Where are you taking from that VS 2013 *has a problem with the initialization of arrays*?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy Its c++

Comment: @Filburt Everything I have seen online says that it doesn't support arrays like this and only supports older versions.  The error is C2536 and there are people who have given fixes but they are all for int and I don't know how to apply that to code to work for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote it won't compile because you can't initialize a non-static array within the definition. This works though:

```
#include <array>
class a{
public:
    a() : words({"cake","pie","steak"})
    {
    }

    std::array<std::string, 3> words;
};
```

Comment: Could you shortly explain what you mean by "can't initialize a non-static array within the definition"?  Or just tell me what to google to understand it, thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
class a{
public:
  string words[3];

  a::a() {
    words[0] = "cake";
    words[1] = "pie";
    words[2] = "steak";
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes that works, thank you!  But one thing- what are you doing when you use the code "a::a()", sorry but I've never come to figure that out.  Or just tell me what to Google to learn, thanks.

Comment: Search for "constructor"